# How to build a Cypher / APOC query in Neo4J 3.x which searches on two different relationship types?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Currently I use the following Cypher / APOC query to search the relationship type `TO` by a certain property (`user` id):

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD rel, start, end
WITH DISTINCT rel, start, end
MATCH (ctx:Context)
WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid 
ETURN DISTINCT start.uid AS source_id,
start.name AS source_name,
end.uid AS target_id,
end.name AS target_name,
rel.uid AS edge_id,
ctx.name AS context_name,
rel.statement AS statement_id,
rel.weight AS weight;
```

I want to make it posible to not only search the index `TO` but also the index `AT` (`AT` type of relationships), so that the resulting `rel` parameter contains both `TO` and `AT` relationships.

I would imagine it would be something as simple as adding an `OR` operator, like this:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') OR
apoc.index.relationships('AT','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD rel, start, end
WITH DISTINCT rel, start, end
MATCH (ctx:Context)
WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid
RETURN DISTINCT start.uid AS source_id,
start.name AS source_name,
end.uid AS target_id,
end.name AS target_name,
rel.uid AS edge_id,
ctx.name AS context_name,
rel.statement AS statement_id,
rel.weight AS weight;
```

But it doesn't work...

Maybe there's somethign I could do that I get the `rel`s from these two `apoc`s and then simply conflate them together into one `rel` but I don't really get how to do that... Or maybe there's an easier way I don't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the use of [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/union/) clause:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD rel, start, end
WITH DISTINCT rel, start, end
MATCH (ctx:Context)
WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid
RETURN DISTINCT start.uid AS source_id,
start.name AS source_name,
end.uid AS target_id,
end.name AS target_name,
rel.uid AS edge_id,
ctx.name AS context_name,
rel.statement AS statement_id,
rel.weight AS weight
UNION
CALL apoc.index.relationships('AT','user:16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff') YIELD rel, start, end
WITH DISTINCT rel, start, end
MATCH (ctx:Context)
WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid
RETURN DISTINCT start.uid AS source_id,
start.name AS source_name,
end.uid AS target_id,
end.name AS target_name,
rel.uid AS edge_id,
ctx.name AS context_name,
rel.statement AS statement_id,
rel.weight AS weight
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [run cypher fragment](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_running_cypher_fragments):

```
WITH '16c01100-aa92-11e3-a3f6-35e25c9775ff' as userId

CALL apoc.cypher.run("
     CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','user:' + $id) YIELD rel
     RETURN rel
", {id: userId}) YIELD value
WITH userId, collect(value.rel) as r1

CALL apoc.cypher.run("
     CALL apoc.index.relationships('AT','user:' + $id) YIELD rel
     RETURN rel
", {id: userId}) YIELD value
WITH r1, collect(value.rel) as r2

UNWIND (r1 + r2) as rel
WITH rel, nodeStart(rel) as start, nodeEnd(rel) as end
MATCH (ctx:Context)
WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid
RETURN DISTINCT start.uid AS source_id,
                start.name AS source_name,
                end.uid AS target_id,
                end.name AS target_name,
                rel.uid AS edge_id,
                ctx.name AS context_name,
                rel.statement AS statement_id,
                rel.weight AS weight;
```